# Magento: Конфликт SMTP Pro и формой обратной связи

Tags: form, smtp, magento

В magento установлено расширения SMTP Pro. При добавлении формы обратной связи не отсылает письмо. Выдает ошибку:

> Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later

Убираю расширения - форма работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

А все остальные письма рассылаются?

Если нет то нужно правильно настроить модуль, чтобы при "selftes" проверке все было ок и приходило тестовое письмо, так же для решения проблемы нужно посмотреть в логи скорее всго там написано что-то полезное что поможет решить данную проблему.